# Flippy-do in my flip-a-roo

Tags: animation

I've an issue while trying to create a simple animation where, when I create a flip between two identical frames, there's [this other flip](https://gyazo.com/a70da0f85c1d2c3eee25703dcc9cf72c) that presents--- but ONLY when that last frame is involved. It's identical to my first frame. I've had it on Quanternium Eruler, XYZ Eruler, I've cleared all the frames between first and last... I've cleared ALL frames... I've changed the position of the last frame as compared to how it was originally. The only time it goes away is when there is NO last frame.

Comment: Please show your work in a style that explains as much as possible.  Screen captures and GIFs are possible. You question is rather vague at this time.  Placing your info at BSE is preferred rather  than external websites.

Comment: There -is- a gyazo in my post, if you click on 'this other flip', but here's the link (( https://gyazo.com/a70da0f85c1d2c3eee25703dcc9cf72c ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Change the x- rotation of the last key-frame to be -360 instead of zero and insert the newkeyframe with  <kbd>I</kbd>

Comment: Aww, man, it's the simple things that get overlooked--- been three days now... Granted, I'm still learning Blender so, I've never payed attention to that stuff, since I've had no understanding of it. Thank you so much!